Asian horror film about a haunted doll associated with a section of forest that is being demolished to make homes
I think I watched this about 3-4 years ago, but it was definitely after 2010, I think on a streaming service. I remember it as that my wife wanted to watch a specific recent horror film, maybe The Boy, and I instead ran into this one, maybe on Netflix or Tubi. It was not in English (although I couldn't tell you the specific language), but was subtitled. A man manages a construction crew that is clearing a wooded section for a housing project. When he
arrives on site, early in the film, he finds that all work has stopped. When asked about it, the workers point to a doll, tied to a tree, and claim that it's a cursed item, and that they will not disturb it. Incensed at their superstitious nature, the man pilots the bulldozer himself, taking the tree down. I don't remember if he then takes the doll, but it winds up in his house. He might have brought it home for his younger daughter. And then, as one might expect, the haunting begins.
Only a few scenes have stuck out in my head. His wife winds up being the one menaced throughout much of the film. There was one scene where she sees her daughter (or maybe a neighbor's child) in a raincoat (poncho?) with a hood during heavy rain and calls her in, only to find out shortly thereafter that it is instead the ghost (I think she finds out via a phone call), prompting her to try to hide in the house. I remember a scene where either the man or his wife are going down a set of stairs inside the house while the windows around them are bursting inwards. I think the ghost is revealed to be from a young girl who was murdered, although the details escape me. And lastly, the man puts the doll back at the construction site (maybe on the stump of the tree he got it from), and I think the haunting ends.
I remember the body count of the film being low, maybe 1-2 people killed in total. I don't remember any elaborate special effects other than the windows bursting open, and I think maybe a scene where the ghost in the raincoat starts having darkness billow around them after the reveal of their ghostly nature. All of the actors were Asian of some sort, and I think there was an underlying theme about the desire for housing projects like the one the protagonist lived in being an unhealthy display of consumerism. The doll itself was either a baby doll, or a more crudely made rag or corn husk doll.
I think the title in English was fairly simple, something like "The Doll". No idea what the original title might have been.

You might be remembering The Doll (2016) from Indonesia.
In the trailer, you can see the doll tied to the tree at the husband's construction site at 0m17s.
Also in the trailer, you can see the girl in the raincoat at 1m48s.



Based merely on the trailer, the only detail that doesn't seem to match your memory is that the husband seems to get someone else to cut down the tree with a chainsaw, rather than knocking it down himself with a bulldozer.
The Doll is the first in a series, including The Doll 2 (2017) and Sabrina (2018).

facepalm I kept seeing that one pop up, but kept discarding it because the reviews didn't quite sound right.
